# Hide images onload contained in a select filter

Tags: jquery, filter, hide

http://jsfiddle.net/DH8HQ/1/

```
    function itemInSpot(drag_item,spot)
{
var oldSpotItem = $(spot).find('img');
if(oldSpotItem.length>100) {
    oldSpotItem.appendTo('#itembox4').draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
}
var item = $('<img />');
item.attr('src',drag_item.attr('src')).attr('class',drag_item.attr('class')).appendTo(spot).draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
drag_item.remove(); // remove the old object
}

 $(document).ready(function() {
$("img").draggable({ revert: 'invalid'});

$("#itembox4").droppable()
$("#pricebox").droppable({ accept: '.price'})
$('#pricebox').droppable({ accept: '.price'});
$('#pricebox,#pricebox,#itembox4').bind('drop', function(ev,ui) {  itemInSpot(ui.draggable,this); });

$('#clone_button').click(function() {
    $('#clone_wrapper div:#pricebox')
        .clone()
        .append('')
        .appendTo($('#clone_wrapper'));
})
});
$('#filter').change(function(){
    $('#itembox4 img').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

At the moment when you load all the images in the Inventory box `#itembox4` show. I need to change this because once its complete there will be over 800 images contained in the box. Currently when the page loads the filter option displays 'select' but none of the images have a class of 'select'.

**So my question is**
How do I make all the images hide until a filter option is selected via the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
 $('#itembox4 img').hide();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/DH8HQ/2/

Comment: Hey not sure if it was just because of this, but when there are multiple images with the same class its only showing one instead of all.

Comment: @KennenLasuni That is because you have duplicate ids in case of multiple images, which is not valid.. Use class instead..